# Showing that a limit is false, did I prove it?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

I want to show that $\lim_{x \to 2} x = 5$ is false.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. If this limit equivalence were true, we would need a $\delta$ such that $|x - 5| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x-2| < \delta$.

$|x - 5| < \epsilon$ can be rewritten to $3-\epsilon < x - 2 < 3 + \epsilon$ or $|x-2| < \min(3 + \epsilon, \epsilon - 3) = \epsilon - 3$

However, we cannot set $\delta = \epsilon - 3$, since for $\epsilon \leq 3$, we have $\delta \leq 0$, which does not satisfy our original requirement that $0 < |x-2| < \delta$.

Comment: Yes, you proved it.

Comment: @ir7 I don't think it is

Comment: "We can not set $\delta =\epsilon -3$".  We need to show we can't set delta to *anything*.  Thing is, if $\epsilon <3$ we $|x-2|<\epsilon \implies $|x-5|>\epsilon $.  For any $\delta $ the $|x-2|< \min (\epsilon, \delta) $ won't give <$|x-5|<\epsilon $.

Comment: Nah. Epsilon-3 is delta’s best chance to exist. Anything less than that is certainly negative, given that epsilon is already positive.

Comment: So, basically, take epsilon equal to 1, and delta is nowhere to find.

Comment: @fleablood I am assuming that the negation of $\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta, (0 < |x-2| < \delta) \implies (|x-5|<\epsilon)$ is $\exists \epsilon, \forall \delta, (0 < |x-2| < \delta) \land \lnot(|x-5|<\epsilon)$ but I don't know if this is even right, and if it is, how to show it

Comment: I think that is correct.  You can show it the way I did.  You are on the right track and have done all the work.  I just don't think you have explained the conclusion as clearly as it could be.

Comment: @fleablood I don't know how to show that for all delta we fail to satisfy the epsilon condition. The righthand inequality of $0 < |x-2| < \delta$ can be rearranged to $|x-5| < \min(\delta - 3, \delta + 3) = \delta-3$ but I don't know if this is on the right track.

Comment: Example.  If |x-2|<1 then |x-5|>2.  For any $d>0$ then then for |x-2|<min (1,d)<= d will have |x-5|>2.  So for any e<2 we can't do it.  Because all |x-2|<min (1,d) <=d will fail.

Comment: I don't see how any of that follows. How do you know that |x-2|<1 implies |x-5|>2? Based on my inequality math above if |x-2|<1 then |x-5| < -2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By contradiction suppose that

$$\lim_{x \to 2} x = 5$$

then by definition of limit we have that $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists\delta>0$ such that $\forall x$

$$0<|x-2|<\delta \implies |x-5|<\epsilon$$

but for $ \epsilon=1$

$$|x-5|<1\iff 4<x<6$$

and for $\delta<1$

$$|x-2|<1\iff 1<x<3$$

then

$$\lim_{x \to 2} x \neq 5$$

Note that from the logical point of view since the definition is

$$\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = L\right) \iff \Big(\forall \varepsilon >0\, \exists \delta > 0: \big(0<\vert x-a\vert <\delta \implies \vert f(x)-L\vert <\varepsilon\big)\Big)$$

the negation is

$$\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) \neq L\right) \iff \Big(\exists \varepsilon >0\, \forall \delta > 0: \big(0<\vert x-a\vert <\delta \not\Rightarrow \vert f(x)-L\vert <\varepsilon\big)\Big).$$

Comment: Can you please show how you are actually getting to these results? When numbers are pulled out of nowhere I don't understand how they satisfy everything. I believe the negation of $\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta, (0 < |x-2| < \delta) \implies (|x-5|<\epsilon)$ is $\exists \epsilon, \forall \delta, (0 < |x-2| < \delta) \land \lnot(|x-5|<\epsilon)$

Comment: How do I show that when $0 < |x-2| < \delta$ is true for all $\delta$, we can find an $\epsilon$ to make  $|x-5| < \epsilon$ false?

Comment: The first step is clear? for $\epsilon<3$ we have $|x-2|<3-\epsilon$. Now if we set $\epsilon=1$  we have $|x-2|<2$ that is $0<x<4$ then the limit can’t be 5.

Comment: I do not think it is true that $3 - \epsilon < x - 2 < 3 + \epsilon$ implies $|x - 2| < \min(3 + \epsilon, 3 - \epsilon)$. I think you have to negate the lowerbound part $3 - \epsilon$ when you convert it back to an absolute value, i.e. $|x - 2| < \min(3 + \epsilon, \epsilon - 3)$, right?

Comment: yes I get your doubt and you’re absolutely right, I fix this point!

Comment: I’ve revised, the idea is to show that for $\delta$ small the definition of limit can’t be satisfied.

Comment: Doesn't it have to be shown that the epsilon condition is false for all delta (given some epsilon), not just a specific range of delta?

Comment: If your doubt is on the logical negation I will add something else.

Comment: The point for the negation is that we need of course $\forall \delta>0$ but the condition for the limit is in the whole interval $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

Comment: "If this limit does not equal L, then for all delta > 0 there exists an epsilon > 0 such that 0 < |x-a| < delta for all x in that range does not imply |f(x)-L| < epsilon" is it not?

Comment: @user536260: if the limit equation is true then for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ which works nicely and if the limit equation is false then *obviously* it means that there is some $\epsilon>0$ for which no $\delta >0$ works nicely. The obvious part in last sentence is not a result of study of logical quantifiers but plain common sense. Convince yourself that it is obvious.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Right, but I can't seem to find the correct conditions for epsilon for that to be the case. 0 < |x-2| < delta can be rearranged to x!=2 and |x-5| < delta - 3. If |x-5| < delta - 3 implied |x-5| < epsilon then delta - 3 <= epsilon would be true. But since we're looking for the negation, this is no longer implied when epsilon < delta - 3... but then this doesn't make any sense if delta is <= 3

Comment: @user536260: also algebraic manipulation of inequalities does not help too much here. One has to see how he inequalities related to $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ come in conflict with each other as we choose some small $\epsilon $. Try to analyze $2-\delta<x<2+\delta $ and $5-\epsilon <x<5+\epsilon $. Cont'd..

Comment: @user536260: these inequalities come in conflict if $2+\delta<5-\epsilon$ ie $\epsilon <3-\delta$. Just choose $\epsilon<3$ like $\epsilon=2.99999$ and you will have a conflict as soon as $\delta <3-\epsilon=0.00001$.

Comment: @user536260 : in general we choose simpler value like $\epsilon=1$ or $2$ rather than $2.99999$ but the logic to choose the $\epsilon$ is the one in my previous comment.

Comment: I think I have it down to epsilon < 3 + delta proving the limit false, but I am not 100% yet

Comment: @user536260 : you should get $\epsilon <3-\delta$ rather than $3+\delta$.

Comment: I'll post my work in another answer

Answer (score 1):

$0 < |x-2| < \delta$ can be rearranged to $x \neq 2$ and $-3-\delta < x-5 < \delta - 3$.

$|x-5| < \epsilon$ can be rearranged to $-\epsilon < x-5 < \epsilon$

If the former condition implied the latter, we'd have $-\epsilon \leq -3-\delta$ and $\delta - 3 \leq \epsilon$.

This simplifies to $\epsilon \geq 3 + \delta$.

Since we are after the negation of this, we have:

$\epsilon < 3 + \delta$

Since $\delta > 0$, this suggests any $\epsilon \leq 3$ should prove the limit false regardless of $\delta$, i.e. you won't be able to find a $\delta$ that works. Unless I made a mistake with this somewhere.

Comment: That seems correct, indeed just when $\epsilon = 3$ we can find a $\delta>0$ such that $x=2-\delta$ doesn't fulfil the condition. The idea is to fix $\epsilon$ sufficiently small in order to have the preimage of the interval around the limit not containing the limit point (x=2 in this case).

Comment: Well your inequalities $\delta+3\leq \epsilon, \delta-3\leq \epsilon $ can be combined into just $\delta+3\leq \epsilon$.

Comment: This implies that as long $\epsilon> 3$ you will be able to get a suitable $\delta$, but once you have $\epsilon \leq 3$ you will start having problems choosing $\delta $. This works out fine.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You're right; simplified those two inequalities into one piece.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon_0:=1$. Given any $\delta>0$ put
$x:=2-{\delta\over2}$. Then $|x-2|<\delta$, but  $|x-5|\geq1$. It follows that no $\delta>0$ whatsoever suffices for the given $\epsilon_0$.